# Can I tell whether a mousewheel event has already been handled by a scroll bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousewheel

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

I have a page that has an area with horizontal scroll on it, and I want the user to be able to scroll left and right by using a mousewheel event (https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/blob/master/jquery.mousewheel.js) -- so I am listening for a mousewheel event on my horizontal scroll area and scrolling it if I see that there's any deltaY.

However, If there's a component inside the horizontal scrollbar, I want it to scroll vertically, and NOT bubble up and cause a scroll on the horizontal scroller.

So assuming the simplified markup looks like this - where .horizontal provides a thin horizontal content and #vertical is vertically scrollable:

```
<div class="horizontal">
    <div id="noscroll"></div>
    <div id="vertical"></div>
</div>
```

And there's some javascript that looks something like this:

```
$('body').on('.horizontal', 'mousewheel', function(e){
  // check whether e has already triggered a scroll on an element
  if(hasAlreadyScrolledSomething(e)){ // how can I implement hasAlreadyScrolledSomething 
    e.stopPropagation();
  } else {
    // scroll the horizontal scroll bar using deltaY
    // this part is already implemented
  }
});
```

Is there anything in the event for mousewheel that I could look at to figure it out? Keep in mind that there can be stuff inside of #vertical, so e.target might not be #vertical, but something on the inside.

Edit: here's the code some sample code to see the concept. http://jsfiddle.net/jTskZ/

Comment: Could you provide a demo on JSFiddle with what you're trying to achieve? I just want to be 100% sure I understand your issue.

Comment: @amustill http://jsfiddle.net/jTskZ/ -- notice that when I scroll the red/yellow part it also scrolls the blue part.

Comment: @ShyGuy If you bind to the `mousewheel` event, your handler will execute *before* the "default action". Just call `e.preventDefault();` from within your handler to prevent that default action.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas but the default action occurs on the #vertical div already (scrolling up and down) and then bubbles up to the .horizontal div. I want to see whether anything inside of it has scrolled vertically, and if it has, don't do the horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
$( '.horizontal' ).on( 'mousewheel', function ( e, delta, deltaX, deltaY ) {
    if ( deltaY && !$( e.target ).closest( '#vertical' )[0] ) {
       this.scrollLeft -= ( deltaY * 30 );   
    }
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/jTskZ/1/

So, from within the handler, you check if the mouse cursor is located *over* the `#vertical` element. If it isn't, you do the horizontal scroll.

Comment: This works for this example, but not exactly what I had in mind -- I was hoping for something more generic where I don't necessarily know what elements inside the horizontal scroll area have vertical scroll content.

Comment: @ShyGuy You could have a generic `'scrollable'` class for things that scroll on your page. Then you would check if there is such a scrollable element beneath the cursor, and if there is, don't do your scroll command. The problem with your `hasAlreadyScrolledSomething` idea is that there's no event that fires *after* the browser does his native scroll, so it is not possible to hook up a callback directly after that event.